# Linked list c++ , expected primary expression before ->

Tags: c++, linked-list

im trying to learn linked lists in c++; my code look like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
struct node{

    int number;
    node *next;

};

struct zoznam{

    node *head=NULL;
    node *tail=NULL;

};

void insertAsFirst(node *&head,node *&last, int number){

    node *tmp = new node;
    tmp->number = number;
    tmp->next=NULL;
    head=tmp;
    last=tmp;

}
void insertValues( node *&head , node *&last, int number){

    if(head==NULL){
        insertAsFirst(zoznam->head,zoznam->tail,number);
    }else{

        node *tmp = new node;
        tmp->number=number;
        tmp->next=NULL;
        last->next=tmp;
        //last=tmp;


    }
}
int main()
{
    for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        insertValues(zoznam->head,zoznam->tail,i);
    }
    node *current=zoznam->head;
    while(current!=NULL){
        cin<<current->number << endl;
        current=current->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

> expected primary-expression before '->' token|

Being new to c++ , i have no idea what the error means , how can i fix that , i tried to check it up but found nothing. Thanks

Comment: `zoznam` is a type name, so `zoznam->head` isn't valid. Create an instance and use it.

Comment: Additionally, dumping a few pages of code, then stating that the problem is some kind of a compilation error, but without indicating which line the compiler error is on, only makes it more difficult to identify the problem. Always be explicit, and specify where exactly the compilation error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

As you're new to C++, I am giving you some details.

When you are using `struct` I mean you define any `struct` then it becomes a type name not a variable. To use that you need to declare variable(s) of that type.

Here, in the `main`, you're using `zoznam`, which is a type name and the definition of that type is the definition of the `struct`.

**Declaration:** `zoznam var_name;`

**Use:** `var_name.head;` or '`var_name.tail`;'.

Learn more about [struct](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/structures/) and [pointer](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/). Read the documentations carefully not only the example codes in this two link.